# How to Allow Only One Checkbox to be Checked

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to create a checkbox that allow only One Checkbox to be Checked

```
var checkbox = ui.Checkbox('A', false);
checkbox.onChange(function(checked) {
  if (checked) {
    Map.onClick(function(coords){
    var location = 'ลองจิจูด: ' + coords.lon.toFixed(4) + ' ' +
                    'ละติจูด: ' + coords.lat.toFixed(4);
    var click_point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
    var demValue1 = dataset1.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), click_point, 90);
    var demValue2 = dataset2.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), click_point, 90);
    var demValue3 = dataset3.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), click_point, 90);
    var demText = 'ศักยภาพน้ำบาดาล: ระดับที่ ' + demValue1.get('b1').getInfo();
    var demText0 = 'คุณภาพน้ำบาดาล';
    var demText2 = 'ด้านการเกษตร_บ่อระดับลึก: ระดับ ' + demValue2.get('b1').getInfo();
    var demText3 = 'ด้านการเกษตร_บ่อระดับตื้น: ระดับ ' + demValue3.get('b1').getInfo();
    toolPanel.widgets().set(1, ui.Label(location));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(2, ui.Label(demText));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(3, ui.Label(demText0));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(4, ui.Label(demText2));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(5, ui.Label(demText3));
    Map.layers().set(1, ui.Map.Layer(click_point, {color: 'FF0000'}));
    })} 
  else {
    null
  }})
  
var checkbox1 = ui.Checkbox('H', false);
checkbox1.onChange(function(checked1) {
  if (checked1) {
    
    Map.onClick(function(coords){
    var location = 'ลองจิจูด: ' + coords.lon.toFixed(4) + ' ' +
                    'ละติจูด: ' + coords.lat.toFixed(4);
    var click_point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
    var demValue1 = dataset1.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), click_point, 90);
    var demValue4 = dataset4.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), click_point, 90);
    var demValue5 = dataset5.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), click_point, 90);
    var demText = 'ศักยภาพน้ำบาดาล: ระดับที่ ' + demValue1.get('b1').getInfo();
    var demText0 = 'คุณภาพน้ำบาดาล';
    var demText4 = 'ด้านการอุปโภคบริโภค_บ่อระดับลึก: ระดับ ' + demValue4.get('b1').getInfo();
    var demText5 = 'ด้านการอุปโภคบริโภค_บ่อระดับตื้น: ระดับ ' + demValue5.get('b1').getInfo();
    toolPanel.widgets().set(1, ui.Label(location));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(2, ui.Label(demText));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(3, ui.Label(demText0));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(4, ui.Label(demText4));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(5, ui.Label(demText5));
    Map.layers().set(1, ui.Map.Layer(click_point, {color: 'FF0000'}));
    })} 
  else {
    null
  }})

var checkbox2 = ui.Checkbox('I', false);
checkbox2.onChange(function(checked2) {
  if (checked2) {
    
    Map.onClick(function(coords){
    var location = 'ลองจิจูด: ' + coords.lon.toFixed(4) + ' ' +
                    'ละติจูด: ' + coords.lat.toFixed(4);
    var click_point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
    var demValue1 = dataset1.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), click_point, 90);
    var demValue6 = dataset6.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), click_point, 90);
    var demValue7 = dataset7.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), click_point, 90);
    var demText = 'ศักยภาพน้ำบาดาล: ระดับที่ ' + demValue1.get('b1').getInfo();
    var demText0 = 'คุณภาพน้ำบาดาล';
    var demText6 = 'การใช้เพื่ออุตสาหกรรม_บ่อระดับลึก: ระดับ ' + demValue6.get('b1').getInfo();
    var demText7 = 'การใช้เพื่ออุตสาหกรรม_บ่อระดับตื้น: ระดับ ' + demValue7.get('b1').getInfo();
    toolPanel.widgets().set(1, ui.Label(location));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(2, ui.Label(demText));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(3, ui.Label(demText0));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(4, ui.Label(demText6));
    toolPanel.widgets().set(5, ui.Label(demText7));
    Map.layers().set(1, ui.Map.Layer(click_point, {color: 'FF0000'}));
    })} 
  else {
    null
  }})



Map.add(checkbox)
Map.add(checkbox1)
Map.add(checkbox2)
ui.root.add(toolPanel);
```

Comment: Would a drop down menu be a suitable alternative? https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ui_widgets#ui.select